# django dropdown menu selection giving 403 POST request error

Tags: python, django, post

i'd like to select an `order_id` from a drop down menu, which will end up querying my MySQL data for the start point latitude/longitude and end point latitude/longitude for the selected taxi ride. i've looked at tutorials online but when i check the network tab of my inspect element, my dropdown selection gives me the following:

```
[17/Mar/2021 14:58:29] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 2294
```

and none of my data ends up being queried.

what am i doing wrong? (also, because I'm using Django 1.6.11, i've inserted the code for JSONResponse instead of importing it from `django.http`)

**base.html**

```
<body>
    <div class="order">
        <h1>View and calculate distance per order</h1>
        <select name="dropdown_menu" id="dropdown_menu">
            <option class="dropdown" type="dropdown" selected>-- Select Order ID -- </option>
            {% for order in orders %}
            <!-- for x in {context}-->
            <option value="{{ order.order_id }}"> {{ order.order_id }} </option>
            {% endfor %}

        </select>

        <p>The selected order id is {{dropdown_menu}}</p>
        <!-- render distance calculation -->
        <!-- render distance on folium -->
    </div>
    {% block javascript %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#dropdown_menu").change(function () { // calling select id
            const order_id_selected = $(this).val();  // get the selected subject ID from the HTML dropdown list 
            $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
                type: "POST",
                url: '',
                data: {
                    'order_id_selected': order_id_selected,       // add the order id to the POST parameters
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                },
                success: function (data) {   // `data` is from `homepage` view function
                    let html_data = '<option value="">---------</option>';
                    data.forEach(function (data) {
                        html_data += `<option value="${data.id}">${data.title}</option>`
                    });
                    $("#dropdown_menu").html(html_data); // replace the contents of the topic input with the data that came from the server
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    {% endblock javascript %}
</body>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.contrib import messages
from django.utils import simplejson
from .models import Member, Driver, Order, Distance

class JsonResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    Code for JSONResponse - not in Django 1.6.11
    """
    def __init__(self, content, mimetype='application/json', status=None, content_type=None):
        super(JsonResponse, self).__init__(
            content=simplejson.dumps(content),
            mimetype=mimetype,
            status=status,
            content_type=content_type,
        )

# def test(request):
#     return render(request, 'base.html')

# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):
    orders = Distance.objects.all().order_by("order")

    if request.method == "POST":  # 
        print("POST")
        order_id_selected = request.POST.get("dropdown_menu", None)
        if order_id_selected: 
            print(order_id_selected)
            try:
                start_lat = Distance.object.filter(id = 'start_lat')
                start_long = Distance.object.filter(id = 'start_long')
                end_lat = Distance.object.filter(id = 'end_lat')
                end_long = Distance.object.filter(id = 'start_long')
            except Exception:
                data['error_message'] = 'error'
                return JsonResponse(data)
        return render(request, 'base.html', {
            # 'members': members,
            # 'drivers': drivers,
            'orders': orders,
            'dropdown_menu': order_id_selected,
        }
        )
    else: # current view defaults to else
        return render(request, 'base.html', {
            'orders': orders,
        })
```

Comment: It looks like you're sending the id to the view in a field named "order_id_selected", not "dropdown_menu". Take a look for `request.POST.get("order_id_selected", None)`

Comment: Also the code after that `if order_id_selected: ` is very weird. Firstly you write `Distance.object` when it should be `Distance.objects` (notice the `s`). Also why do you have that try-except for no reason? (In fact what are those filters even meant to do?)

Comment: @Ben same error :/ from the tutorials i've seen, it seems like `request.POST.get` should take in `(html-select-tag-name, None)` as arguments.

Comment: @cookiestarninja you are not using a form. You have written this line `'order_id_selected': order_id_selected,` while making the ajax request meaning what Ben says above is correct.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat + Ben thanks for the clarifications!

Answer (score 0):

Where is your form tag? You missed that.

Also do specify the form method
And remember also your card token

**EDIT**

Change

```
$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
```

To

```
"{{csrf_token}}"
```

Comment: i'm not using django's form/modelform api